Vertx and kubernetes client http client factory
I have a vert.x app running on 4.5.11 and I am creating an Openshift client using fabric libraries. The vertx http factory creates a new vert.x object in the vertx http client factory in the kubernetes vertx httpclient. How can I pass the vertx instance to it so that it doesn’t create a new vert.x instance.

The file I am referring to is: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/v7.0.0/httpclient-vertx/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/vertx/VertxHttpClientFactory.java

It's not currently possible to pass an existing instance to the factory, as the Fabric8 client needs to ensure that the Vert.x client is properly configured.
That said, maybe we could make it easier to reuse an existing client? Please do open an issue at https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/.
Edit: One option would be to create your own factory and pass it to the client builder when configuring the client.
Edit2: The client in version 7.0.1 will allow the possibility to pass a Vert.x instance to the factory. See https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/pull/6726/files for more details.
